# Why can't my user access a certain page?

Tags: drupal-6

In the user's roles "site developer" is checked.
In the permission's page for "site developer", "developer" is checked

In my module I have the following:

```
$items['batch/delete'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'batch_delete',
  'access arguments' => array('developer'),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
```

They are getting an error in Chrome: This webpage has a redirect loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had 'batch/delete' defined somewhere else, so I changed it and now it works.